# Does subversion branch/tag work when there is difference between local and trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I checked out the whole java project, but when I am about to commit those files I changed, I encounter a problem.

Say, I checked out a.java and made some changes to it. But someone changed it too and committed to trunk. I did some research and it seems I could do a branch operation so that I could add the changes in trunk into a.java but also keep my stuff in it.

But not sure whether it's correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to commit your changes to a.java, you first have to update your local copy to incorporate the changes the other user checked in.  Then you should be able to commit your changes to trunk with no branching needed.

If their changes are in a different part of the file, your subversion client should merge their changes into your local file with no problems.  If their changes overlap yours, it will probably launch a file editor so you can fix the conflicting edits.  Conflicting lines will be marked with <<<<<< or >>>>>> to indicate which line came from which version of the file.  Before you check in, make sure the merge hasn't broken your code!

Comment: Thanks ejegg. That really helps. I was worried if I did the update, my changes would be lost but seems they are still there.